# Nested While Loop Big O . estimate

Tags: performance, big-o, nested-loops

```c
int i = 0;
int n = 20;

while (i < n)
{
  i++;
  int j = i;

  while (i < n)
  {
    printf("this is %d", i);
    i++;
  }

  i = j;
}
```

So to estimate the **time complexity** of this function, my approach to estimating is that the outer loop runs `n` times. The inner loop runs `n - 1` times? so would the *time complexity* for this nested loop be `O(n^2)`?

Comment: what's the value of i?

Answer (score 1):

You can *rewrite* the initial code

```
int n = 20;
int i = 0;

while (i < n) 
{
  i++;
  int j = i;

  while (i < n) 
  {
    printf("this is %d",i);

    i++;
  }

  i = j;
}
```

into its *equivalent*:

```
int n = 20;

for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) 
  for (int j = i; j < n; ++j)
    printf("this is %d", j);
```

Now it's evident that you have `O(n**2)` time complexity: you have

```
(n - 1) + (n - 2) + (n - 3) + ... + 3 + 2 + 1 = n * (n - 1) / 2
```

operations (`printf(...)`) and

```
O(n * (n - 1) / 2) = O(n**2 / 2 - n / 2) = O(n**2)
```

Comment: @tyc72, [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ;)

Answer (score 0):

In subsequent iterations, inner loop runs as many times as n-1, n-2, n-3,..., 1. So the sum is n(n-1)/2, which leads to the asymptotic time complexity as O(n^2).